# O365 management API stopped working

Tags: office-365, office365apis

I'm running a web hook which uses the [O365 mangement API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office-365/office-365-management-activity-api-reference) to obtain activities for SharePoint. This worked until yesterday 10 PM. Suddenly a call to

```
https://manage.office.com/api/v1.0/{TENANT-ID}/activity/feed/subscriptions/list
```

using a bearer token is responding with code `500` or `503` with a huge timeout of up to 1.5 minutes. I cannot figure out what happened. I even redeployed my API but still no success. If I try direct access using Fiddler it fails too.

**EDIT:** The key in Azure AD will expire on ‎9‎/‎20‎/‎2018.